# Difference between println and print in Swift

Tags: swift, println

The use of `println` and `print` in Swift both print to the console. But the only difference between them seems to be that `println` returns to the next line whereas `print` will not.

For example:

```
println("hello world")
println("another world")
```

will output the following two lines:

```
hello world
another world
```

while:

```
print("hello")
print("world")
```

outputs only one line:

```
helloworld
```

The `print` seems to be more like the traditional `printf` in C. The Swift documentation states that `println` is the equivalent to `NSLog` but what's the purpose of `print`, is there any reason to use it other than not returning to the next line?

Comment: This naming is very familiar to those coming from Java. The "LN" in println stands for "line".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the new swift 2, the println has been renamed to print which as an option "terminator" argument.

(udpated 2015-09-16 with the new terminator: "")

```
var fruits = ["banana","orange","cherry"]

// #1
for f in fruits{
    print(f)
}

// #2
for f in fruits{
    print("\(f) ", terminator: "")
}
```

#### #1 will print

```
banana
orange
cherry
```

#### #2 will print

```
banana orange cherry
```

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer since the spec has changed with the release of Swift 2.

Comment: This seems to have changed. `/// - Note: to print without a trailing newline, pass 'terminator: ""`
Looks like the new line is now the default and `appendNewLine`  has been removed.

Comment: As in the new swift 2 just released, the `println` has been renamed to `print`. There are no `println`s anymore. just `print`.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what it is, it's used when you want to print multiple things on the same line.

Comment: Could you provide an example of why you would use `print` instead of `println`?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like you said, to print without adding a new line. There are some cases where you may want this. This is a simple example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

print("My array contains: ")
for num in arr{
    print("\(num) ")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is same as in Java
print is just print
where ln in println means "Next Line".
It will create a next line for you.

Comment: Your answer is obsolete, the syntax has changed, see Jeremy Chone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The deference between print and println is that after print prints the cursor does not skip lines and after println prints the cursor skips a line

Comment: That was the case until Swift 2. Now the syntax has changed, see Jeremy Chone's answer.