# Swift: print() vs println() vs NSLog()

Tags: swift, debugging, logging, console, oslog

What's the difference between `print`, `NSLog` and `println` and when should I use each?

For example, in Python if I wanted to print a dictionary, I'd just `print myDict`, but now I have 2 other options. How and when should I use each?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between println and print in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072775/difference-between-println-and-print-in-swift)

Comment: what about NSLog and printing a NSDictionary doesn't give me anything useful?

Comment: From iOS 10.0 forward it's recommended that one uses `os_log`. Please see my answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42313898/1452174).

Comment: In addition to seeing the Swift documentation on `os_log`: try seeing the [full documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc) of the objective-C page. It's much more **complete**.

Comment: ... and effective iOS 14 (and macOS 11, etc.), use [`Logger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/) in lieu of `os_log`.

Answer (score 948, accepted):

A few differences:

1. `print` vs `println`:

   The `print` function prints messages in the Xcode console when debugging apps.

   The `println` is a variation of this that was removed in Swift 2 and is not used any more. If you see old code that is using `println`, you can now safely replace it with `print`.

   Back in Swift 1.x, `print` did not add newline characters at the end of the printed string, whereas `println` did. But nowadays, `print` always adds the newline character at the end of the string, and if you don't want it to do that, supply a `terminator` parameter of `""`.
2. `NSLog`:

   - `NSLog` adds a timestamp and identifier to the output, whereas `print` will not.
   - `NSLog` statements appear in both the device’s console and debugger’s console whereas `print` only appears in the debugger console.
   - `NSLog` in iOS 10-13/macOS 10.12-10.x uses `printf`-style format strings, e.g.

     ```
      NSLog("%0.4f", CGFloat.pi)
     ```

     that will produce:

     > 2017-06-09 11:57:55.642328-0700 MyApp[28937:1751492] 3.1416
   - `NSLog` from iOS 14/macOS 11 can use string interpolation. (Then, again, in iOS 14 and macOS 11, we would generally favor `Logger` over `NSLog`. See next point.)

   Nowadays, while `NSLog` still works, we would generally use “unified logging” (see below) rather than `NSLog`.
3. Effective iOS 14/macOS 11, we have `Logger` interface to the “unified logging” system. For an introduction to `Logger`, see WWDC 2020 [Explore logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/).

   - To use `Logger`, you must import `os`:

     ```
     import os
     ```
   - Like `NSLog`, unified logging will output messages to both the Xcode debugging console and the device console, too.
   - Create a `Logger` and `log` a message to it:

     ```
     let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "network")
     logger.log("url = \(url)")
     ```

     When you observe the app via the external Console app, you can filter on the basis of the `subsystem` and `category`. It is very useful to differentiate your debugging messages from (a) those generated by other subsystems on behalf of your app, or (b) messages from other categories or types.
   - You can specify different types of logging messages, either `.info`, `.debug`, `.error`, `.fault`, `.critical`, `.notice`, `.trace`, etc.:

     ```
     logger.error("web service did not respond \(error.localizedDescription)")
     ```

     So, if using the external Console app, you can choose to only see messages of certain categories (e.g. only show debugging messages if you choose “Include Debug Messages” on the Console “Action” menu). These settings also dictate many subtle issues details about whether things are logged to disk or not. See WWDC video for more details.
   - By default, non-numeric data is redacted in the logs. In the example where you logged the URL, if the app were invoked from the device itself and you were watching from your macOS Console app, you would see the following in the macOS Console:

     > url = <private>

     If you are confident that this message will not include user confidential data and you wanted to see the strings in your macOS console, you would have to do:

     ```
     logger.log("url = \(url, privacy: .public)")
     ```
   - Note, that in Xcode 15 and later, you can now filter the log by type, subsystem, category, or whatever. Personally, in large projects, I find it useful to use a separate `Logger` for each source file, then I can filter a voluminous log to something more specific (e.g., just log messages of type “error” for a particular “category”, etc.). For more information, see WWDC 2023 video [Debug with structured logging](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10226).
   - Also, unlike `print` and `NSLog`, when you use `Logger` with Xcode 15 or later, you can <kbd>control</kbd>-click (or <kbd>right</kbd>-click, if you have enabled the right mouse button) on a log message in the Xcode console, and choose “Jump to source” to jump to the relevant line of code.
4. Prior to iOS 14/macOS 11, iOS 10/macOS 10.12 introduced  `os_log` for “unified logging”.

   - Import `os.log`:

     ```
     import os.log
     ```
   - You should define the `subsystem` and `category`:

     ```
     let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "network")
     ```
   - When using `os_log`, you would use a printf-style pattern rather than string interpolation:

     ```
     os_log("url = %@", log: log, url.absoluteString)
     ```
   - You can specify different types of logging messages, either `.info`, `.debug`, `.error`, `.fault` (or `.default`):

     ```
     os_log("web service did not respond", type: .error)
     ```
   - You cannot use string interpolation when using `os_log`. For example with `print` and `Logger` you do:

     ```
     logger.log("url = \(url)")
     ```

     But with `os_log`, you would have to do:

     ```
     os_log("url = %@", url.absoluteString)
     ```
   - The `os_log` enforces the same data privacy, but you specify the public visibility in the printf formatter (e.g. `%{public}@` rather than `%@`). E.g., if you wanted to see it from an external device, you'd have to do:

     ```
     os_log("url = %{public}@", url.absoluteString)
     ```
   - You can also use the “Points of Interest” log if you want to watch ranges of activities from Instruments:

     ```
     let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
     ```

     And start a range with:

     ```
     os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Network request")
     ```

     And end it with:

     ```
     os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Network request")
     ```

     For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1271826.
   - Like `Logger`, for `OSLog` you can <kbd>control</kbd>-click ( or <kbd>right</kbd>-click) on the message and jump to the relevant line of code in Xcode 15 and later.

Bottom line, `print` is sufficient for simple logging with Xcode, but unified logging (whether `Logger` or `os_log`) achieves the same thing but offers far greater capabilities.

The power of unified logging comes into stark relief when debugging iOS apps that have to be tested outside of Xcode. For example, when testing background iOS app processes like background fetch, being connected to the Xcode debugger [changes the app lifecycle](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14855). So, you frequently will want to test on a physical device, running the app from the device itself, not starting the app from Xcode’s debugger. Unified logging lets you still watch your iOS device log statements from the macOS Console app.

Comment: Nice summary! To add a few more: you can pass in an NSString to println, but not NSLog; you can add args for NSLog, but not println; Swift style string interpolation sometimes crashes for NSLog, but not println.

Comment: an interesting note about Swift compiler optimisation and the use of print() https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-log-devil-or-why-println-is-dangerous-46390453353d

Comment: @Rob if i use print then does it appear in the debugger console or not?or should we use debugPrint?

Comment: If you use `print`, it shows up in the debug area of Xcode, just like `debugPrint`. The only difference is that `print` ends up calling `description` method of the object, and `debugPrint` calls `debugDescription`, which may be more verbose than `description`.

Comment: @Rob, your answer seems to address issues with logging in Swift. I am trying to relate this to a problem I am having with NSLog in Objective C since I upgraded to Xcode 9 https://stackoverflow.com/q/46397444/2348597

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from a disclaimer or something about how difficult it is for the average user to trigger, retrieve, send a sysdiagnose log...I don't think it used to be that difficult before with `NSLog`. FWIW I've addressed that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728431/apple-recommended-logging-approach-for-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Great writeup, another difference between NSLog and print I've seen is that if you're redirecting the output to a file (with giving stderr/stdout to freopen) then print doesn't get logged into the file in a timely manner like NSLog does, so try not to mix them if you're redirecting to a file!

Comment: Starting from iOS 14/macOS 11 , i also noticed another logging framework from Apple: https://github.com/apple/swift-log. What's the difference with import os?

Comment: @Rob  The truth is if I use that open source via "import Loggin", I can not see any log output in Console.app. This is the puzzle part i have

Comment: @LiangWang - It depends upon what level of logging you are doing with this [open source rendition](https://github.com/apple/swift-log/blob/main/Sources/Logging/Logging.swift) of `Logger`. By default, you’ll see `info` and `error`, but not, for example, `debug` (unless you change `logLevel`, e.g., `logger.logLevel = .debug`).

Comment: "NSLog statements appear in both the device’s console and debugger’s console whereas print only appears in the debugger console". Does this mean neither `NSLog` nor `print` will appear in Sysdiagnose? because they both only send messages to debugger's console and the debugger isn't attached when the logs are happening on the phone?

Comment: The point of that quoted sentence is to point out that `print` and `NSLog` behave differently. In answer to your question, I suspect that `print` would not appear in sysdiagose, but `NSLog` would.

Comment: In an app unattached to XCode, how does print function? Is is still called and then ignored (viz. is it safe/performant to leave print functions lying around or should they be removed, or disabled with a macro?) If it's not called, presumably string interpolation is still run on args to it (or is it removed completely)?

Comment: 1. Benchmark it and you will see performance impact with `print` statements (though not really observably so unless you are doing millions of them). 2. If you use `Logger`, instead, not only do you have the option to see logging statements in the macOS console, but it’s more performant than `print`. 3. With `Logger` or `os_log`, you can define your log to be `.disabled` and you’ll see performance benefit over print in release builds (and you'll be confident that you won't leak anything to the end-user). I use the latter.

Comment: Great article; small typo: 'os_log("url = \(url, privacy: .public)")' should be 'logger.log("url = \(url, privacy: .public)")'

Comment: That typo has been fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 85):

If you're using **Swift 2**, now you can only use print() to write something to the output.

> Apple has combined both **println()** and **print()** functions into
>   one.

**Updated to iOS 9**

By default, the function terminates the line it prints by adding a line break.

```
print("Hello Swift")
```

**Terminator**

To print a value without a line break after it, pass an empty string as the terminator

```
print("Hello Swift", terminator: "")
```

**Separator**

You now can use separator to concatenate multiple items

```
print("Hello", "Swift", 2, separator:" ")
```

**Both**

Or you could combine using in this way

```
print("Hello", "Swift", 2, separator:" ", terminator:".")
```

Comment: `appendNewline` has a default value of `true`

Comment: In iOS (9.0) you need to use `terminator : ""`, e.g. `print("...", terminator: "")`

Comment: The statement in your first sentence is incorrect. NSLog() still works, even in latest Swift 2.x

Answer (score 64):

Moreover, Swift 2 has `debugPrint()` (and `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol).

Don't forget about `debugPrint()` which works like `print()` but [most suitable for **debugging**](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/func/debugPrint/).

Examples:

- **Strings**

  - `print("Hello World!")` becomes `Hello World`
  - `debugPrint("Hello World!")` becomes `"Hello World"` (Quotes!)
- **Ranges**

  - `print(1..<6)` becomes `1..<6`
  - `debugPrint(1..<6)` becomes `Range(1..<6)`

Any class can customize their debug string representation via **`CustomDebugStringConvertible`** protocol.

Comment: `DebugPrintable` protocol has been renamed to [`CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CustomDebugStringConvertible_Protocol/).

Comment: So Swift's `description` is to `debugDescription` as Python's `str` is to `repr`?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 44):

To add to Rob's answer, since iOS 10.0, Apple has introduced an entirely new "Unified Logging" system that supersedes existing logging systems (including ASL and Syslog, NSLog), and also surpasses existing logging approaches in performance, thanks to its new techniques including log data compression and deferred data collection.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging#1682426):

> The unified logging system provides a single, efficient, performant API for capturing messaging across all levels of the system. This unified system centralizes the storage of log data in memory and in a data store on disk.

Apple highly recommends using `os_log` going forward to log all kinds of messages, including info, debug, error messages because of its much improved performance compared to previous logging systems, and its centralized data collection allowing convenient log and activity inspection for developers. In fact, the new system is likely so low-footprint that it won't cause the "observer effect" where your bug disappears if you insert a logging command, interfering the timing of the bug to happen.

[image: Performance of Activity Tracing, now part of the new Unified Logging system]

You can learn more about this in details [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/).

To sum it up: use `print()` for your personal debugging for convenience (but the message won't be logged when deployed on user devices). Then, use Unified Logging (`os_log`) as much as possible for everything else.

Answer (score 15):

**iOS logger**

[[Console Log]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145654/4770877)

1. `NSLog` - add meta info (like timestamp and identifier) and allows you to output **1023 symbols**. Also print message into Console. The slowest method. Is not safe because other applications has an access to log file

   ```
   //@import Foundation //Objective-C
   @import Foundation
   NSLog("SomeString")
   ```
2. `print` - prints **all** string to Xcode. Has better performance than previous

   ```
   //@import Foundation //Objective-C
   import Foundation
   print("SomeString")
   ```
3. `println` (only  available Swift v1) and add `\n` at the end of string
4. `os_log` (from iOS v10) - prints **32768 symbols** also prints to console. Has better performance than previous

   ```
   //@import os.log //Objective-C
   @import os.log
   os_log("SomeIntro: %@", log: .default, type: .info, "someString")
   ```
5. `Logger` (from iOS v14) - prints **32768 symbols** also prints to console. Has better performance than previous

   ```
   //@import os //Objective-C
   import os
   let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "someCategory")

   logger.log("some message \(Date)")
   //some message <private>
   //it is about privacy level

   logger.log("some message \(Date, privacy: .public)")
   //some message 2023-11-11 16:09:03 +0000
   ```

Answer (score 6):

There's another method called `dump()` which can also be used for logging:

> ```
> func dump<T>(T, name: String?, indent: Int, maxDepth: Int, maxItems: Int)
> ```
>
> Dumps an object’s contents using its mirror to standard output.

From [Swift Standard Library Functions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/swift_standard_library_functions)