# Why print() in Swift does not log the time stamp as NSLog in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nslog

From background of Objective C when I use `NSLog()` it prefixes the text with the date time stamp, but when I use `print()` on Swift it only prints the text

So it there is a way to make it print the time stamp as well, or am I doing some thing wrong?

Comment: I'm not particularly sure, but I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that `NSLog` prints to the Console (and your log is visible in Console.app) but `print` in Swift doesn't do that.

Comment: I have no evidence to support this 2nd point, but I believe that Xcode actually takes information from the Console and prints everything in a certain category even if it's not related to the program you're running. I've seen some irrelevant console messages in my Xcode. Maybe Swift's `print` just prints to the Xcode console?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951195/swift-print-vs-println-vs-nslog

Comment: Note that whichever solution you choose, `NSLog` _will_ print output to the console in a release build while `print` will not.  Choose wisely.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Because `print` is not `NSLog`. It is as simple as that.

[`NSLog`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395275-nslog) is a logging tool in Foundation that writes to the Apple System Log facility which appears on the console.

[`print(…)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) is a print function in the Swift Standard Library that writes to standard out, which appears on the console in debug sessions.

You could add `Date()` to your `print` parameter to print the current time and date. (Or `Date().description(with: Locale.current)` to get it in your local time zone.)

Or you could just use `NSLog` which is available in Swift too (if you import Foundation).

Comment: Thanks I tried `NSLog` and it works so I'll work with it in the cases that I need to show the time stamp

Answer (score 36):

**Swift:**

```
NSLog("this will print with dates")
```

Comment: But not printing in Playground

Comment: @Asike have you tried importing Foundation? thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: @Tillus have you tried importing Foundation? this will only work if there is a obj-c runtime, it is not the case in a playground.

Comment: Yes with implementing foundation it is the same. I think OSLog should be used now

Answer (score 12):

This one just outputs a simple timestamp, but can be easily modified to include additional text if you want.

Additionally, it relies on a `lazy` `DateFormatter` to avoid expensive initializations.

```
import Foundation

class Timestamp {
    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS "
        return formatter
    }()

    func printTimestamp() {
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
    }
}

let timestamp = Timestamp()
timestamp.printTimestamp() // 2018-07-05 12:57:08.725
timestamp.printTimestamp() // 2018-07-05 12:57:08.727 (uses the same formatter)
```

Comment: This is one of the correct answers.  Note that `NSLog` _will_ print output to the console in a release build while `print` will not.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a suggested function you can use instead of print()

```
func printLog(log: AnyObject?) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS "
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()), terminator: "")
    if log == nil {
        print("nil")
    }
    else {
        print(log!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an instance of NSDateFormatter is costly. So, ideally, the `formatter` would have to be created only once, outside your method, to avoid calling NSDateFormatter() each time the method is called.

Comment: It is not about what you want - in this case, this should be done.

Answer (score 4):

### iOS 14+

New API `os.Logger.log` with optional `level` parameter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/3551622-log

```swift
import os.Logger

log("Message \(var)")
log(level: .debug, "Message \(var)")
```

### Deprecated ⚠️

You can use the `Logging` os module to do that in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

Specifically `os_log`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/2320718-os_log

```swift
import os.log
os_log("Message %d", type: .info, value)
```

Comment: os_log already seems to be deprecated

Comment: ty @PeterKreinz, updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Make your own class function for print, eg printWithDate() and prepend the date to the output. Then you can use this everywhere without needing to add the date each time you want to print.