# Programming stop execute in iOS when debug?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

Want to build a debug tool to monitor the app, pause execution when bad things occur. Dev can continue run the program after be notified the problem.

May I just throw a exception or use a special signal?

---

I have tried `raise(SIGSTOP)`, looks good.
But the backtrace showed in Xcode is not exactly what I stop it. Can I make a real time stop?

Answer (score 0):

If fatal error comes, it terminates by itself.
If you want to

1) break code execution:
Use **breakpoints**:

http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

2) log output:

- use **NSLog() for Objective-C**
- use **print() for Swift**

[Swift: print() vs println() vs NSLog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951195/swift-print-vs-println-vs-nslog)

Answer (score 0):

Call a NOP method. In Xcode, put a symbolic breakpoint on that method.