# print logs are not showing on my Testflight app on Device connected to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I use `print` to log network responses on my app.

I installed via Testflight, connect to Xcode and run the app.

I'm not seeing these logs.

How do I see these logs?

iOS 10.3.2

Comment: You won't see `print` statement in the device console. Use `NSLog` or, better, `os_log`. And if using macOS 10.12 or later, I'd suggest watching via macOS `Console` app, not Xcode, as it gives you greater control. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951564/1271826

Comment: Thank you for this.