# Is it possible to see iOS framework log and apps log like android?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xcode, logging

I'm not so familiar with iOS development environment.
However I once was Android framework engineer so.. android is easy to me.

In Android devices, we can easily see both Android framework log and apps(which are not developed by me) log. Since we can access the device's folder where logs are archived.

How about iOS?

It seems that I can only see my app's log in the console in Xcode if I run the app through Xcode.

How about other cases? 
Is it possible for me the see below logs?
1.iOS framework log
2.apps log(not developed by me)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the device console in the "Devices" window of XCode:

[image: example]

And the simulator log is saved in this path:

> ~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/6.1/system.log

Comment: Hi Karla. Thank you for your answer I found how to see real-time log. (Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators) I think I can see some iOS framework log and apps log as well as crash log(call stack). However I have another question. What logs are shown in the console? I can't see "print" method logs. The reason why I wonder is that now I'm developing iOS app and it contains many print() methods. Do I have to block all the print methods before launching the app on App Store? (logs from print() shows some sensitive data if I run my app through Xcode)

Comment: Swift `print` method only display messages in debugger console, objective-c `NSLog` displays in both device and debugger console. So if yo are using `print` you don`t have to worry that your logs are compromised.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951195/swift-print-vs-println-vs-nslog) for further info.