# URLSessionDownloadTask weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I have created a class to download file using `URLSession`.

I noticed a weird behavior that when device in debug mode, it is downloading files. But if I remove device and run app manually, downloading is not working at all. 
Sometimes re-attaching device starts the download.

This is how I am creating URLSession :

```
private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
     let config                      = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "org.company.id")
     config.isDiscretionary          = true
     config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
     config.allowsCellularAccess     = true
   return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}()
```

And here is my request download function :

```
func requestDownload(urlString: String){
    guard let url                = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
    downloadTask                 = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.taskDescription = urlString
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Here is a link to that file downloader class : https://github.com/skdevil/PrakrstaFileDownloader

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Debug! Log like crazy. Log into a file you can study after a run. Find out where things go wrong.

Comment: @matt But the problem is when app is not in debug mode. In debug mode its working fine. I will do "unified logging" as suggested by Rob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when you run it attached to your debugger, the app is never suspended, whereas on a device can be.

A couple of observations:

- It is possible you have not implemented [`handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622941-application) in your app delegate or [`urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1617185-urlsessiondidfinishevents) in your `URLSessionDelegate`. They're required for background downloads. We'd need to see those implementations to comment further.

  For more information see [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background).

  FYI, I've issued a [pull request](https://github.com/skdevil/PrakrstaFileDownloader/pull/1) on that repo, showing what you need to do to support background sessions.
- Or, if you've done all of that correctly, note that you've set discretionary mode. This means that it will download when attached to power and wifi. Is that the case?
- Note, I'd encourage doing some logging so you can see what's going on. But you cannot use Xcode's debugging mechanisms for this (because, as you've noticed, being attached to Xcode changes the behavior of the app).

  You can, instead, log using "unified logging" as outlined in WWDC 2016 video [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/). That way, you can watch log messages from your iOS device on your macOS console, and you don't have to write your own file logging system. See point 3 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951564/1271826 for example of how to observe iOS log messages on macOS console. Or see that aforementioned WWDC video.

Comment: Thanks for updating my repo :) . Will do what you suggested and update this question accordingly.

Comment: discretionary mode - This means that it will download when attached to power and wifi. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: I updated my code as per your commit and added in appdelegate too. Still the downloading is working in debug mode only ( sometimes it works without it too but rarely)

Comment: Re `isDiscretionary`, see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary), which confirms that with this set to `true`, the OS has the right to defer the download until it sees fit (generally when on wifi and charging). The idea is that if you're downloading some huge resource, you might not want to unnecessarily consume the device's battery and the user's data plan. Try changing `isDiscretionary` and see if your behavior changes.

Comment: @sharadchauhan - Also note that background sessions (esp discretionary ones) can run slowly, so I don't know how long you're giving it to finish...

Comment: Somehow getting your commit, doing what you suggested and commenting "config.isDiscretionary" this line, it working continuously. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes its taking little time to start but it is downloading.