# swift print not printing to console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason print is not printing anything to the console. I ran the debugger and it's definitely being called.

Do I need to set some kind of setting? I've got "All Output" selected

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
}
```

This is the only thing in my console

[image]

Comment: Have you accidentally filtered the content or chosen something other than `All Output`?

Comment: I haven't added an filters, and it's on all output

Comment: try printing with NSLog and see what happens: NSLog(@"Hello World");

Comment: @LanceSamaria that worked! so that means my console only displays objective C related code? Is there a setting for this?

Comment: No that means that it can print. NSLog displays differently then Print: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951564/4833705

Comment: Did you try exiting Xcode, restarting the simulator and seeing what happens? Did you try hooking it up to a device to see what happens. I have no idea what the problem is but sometimes Xcode gets silly and you have to restart it and the simulator. It's worth a try

Comment: maybe its the version your using? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75439 or this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64123

Comment: hmm I haven't a clue. Ah well, i'll just use NSLog for the time being. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is it possible you (or some library you are using) defined another `print` function? Try `Swift.print("viewDidLoad")`. If that works then you know there is some other `print` function hiding the standard one.

Comment: @TrevorWood I know you discounted it, but the console’s filter is ripe for accidental characters. The suggested filter solution is in Xcode’s UI, not in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried that aswell with no luck

Comment: @dbx I deleted everything in the filter box, no luck. Then restarted xcode and still no luck. I'll try it with an entirely different project to see if it's my xcode or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue

deep in the project, hidden among lines of code...I found!

```
public func debugPrint(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {}
public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {}
```

Actually, it was at the top of AppDelegate...oops